# How to sort nested python dictionary using item's sub-value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to sort nested python dictionary items by their sub-values and save that dictionary items in descending order

Describing dictionary:

Before sorted

```py
my_dict = {
    "Bob": {"Buy": 25, "Sell": 33, "Quantity": 100},
    "Moli": {"Buy": 75, "Sell": 53, "Quantity": 300},
    "Annie": {"Buy": 74, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 96},
    "Anna": {"Buy": 55, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 154},
}
```

I want to sort dictionary items in descending order by their sub-values (i.e., "Quantity") and the output should be like this:

After sorted

```py
my_dict={
    "Moli": {"Buy": 75, "Sell": 53, "Quantity": 300},
    "Anna": {"Buy": 55, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 154},
    "Bob": {"Buy": 25, "Sell": 33, "Quantity": 100},
    "Annie": {"Buy": 74, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 96},
}
```

How can I do it without using any functions like:

```py
def sort_by_quantity(dic):
    keys = sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Quantity']) # list of sorted keys
    return dict((x, y) for x, y in keys) # convert tuple back to dict
```

**or**

```py
sdct = dictt.copy()
def func(d):
    return sdct[d]['Quantity']
dct = sorted(dictt, key=func, reverse=True)
newDict = {i: dictt[i] for i in dct}
print(newDict)
```

**etc...**

The way we do sort in Pandas dataframe like:

```py
df = df1.sort_values('Quantity', ascending=False)
```

I will be very grateful if someone tells me how to do this :) :) :)

Comment: As part of CPython3.6 (implementation detail) or just plaing Python3.7 (design), `dict` items are ordered by insertion time. This means, that the key you insert first is stored first. It doesn't matter if you change the value, it only matters if you delete and recreate that key, in which case it will be placed last again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
my_dict = {
    "Bob": {"Buy": 25, "Sell": 33, "Quantity": 100},
    "Moli": {"Buy": 75, "Sell": 53, "Quantity": 300},
    "Annie": {"Buy": 74, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 96},
    "Anna": {"Buy": 55, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 154}
}

sorted_dict = dict( sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda v: v[1]['Quantity']) )
print(sorted_dict)

# for reverse
sorted_dict_reversed = dict( sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda v: v[1]['Quantity'], reverse=True) )
print(sorted_dict_reversed)
```

Comment: Hi, Salman it's work but it show in ascending order ({'Annie': {'Buy': 74, 'Sell': 83, 'Quantity': 96}, 'Bob': {'Buy': 25, 'Sell': 33, 'Quantity': 100}, 'Anna': {'Buy': 55, 'Sell': 83, 'Quantity': 154}, 'Moli': {'Buy': 75, 'Sell': 53, 'Quantity': 300}, 'reverse': True}) can you tell me how to show in descending order or apply (reverse=True)

Comment: ```sorted_dict = dict( sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda v: v[1]['Quantity'], reverse=True) )```

Comment: sorted method has an attribute called reverse you can you use as I have mentioned above example ```sorted(....., reverse=True)```

Comment: Thanks Salman thank you so much for your help :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this behavior in Python 3.5-, or some implementations of Python 3.6, you will have to use `collections.OrderedDict`. In Python 3.7+, or some implementations of Python 3.6 (such as the standard CPython3.6) the normal `dict` has the same behavior as `collections.OrderedDict`. Form here all, I will call these versions 3.5-* and 3.7+* to indicate that 3.6 may be included in both depending on your Python implementation.

In any case, the mentioned structures sort items by insertion time, so you will need to create a new object.

Dict comprehension (only valid for `dict` in 3.7+*):

```py
my_new_dict = {k: v for k, v in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Quantity'])}
```

Constructor (valid for both `dict` in 3.7+* and `collections.OrderedDict` backwards compatible):

```py
my_new_dict = dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Quantity']))
```

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

my_new_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Quantity']))
```